# How to validate a URLs status

Tags: java, url-validation

I have excelsheet named as Validationstatuscode.xlsx which consists of list of URLs on Column A of sheet 1.
I want to validate all URLs  which show http status 200 or 400. Till now i've used
[http://httpstatus.io/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utGAy.png) to validate 100 URLs at 1 shot but now the count has increased.
So is there possible in java to validate the URLs?
Though i've knowledge in java but dont know how to do this?

Comment: @SaqibRezwan As far as I understand OP is looking for a way to validate the HTTP status, but not whether the URL itself is valid or not.

Comment: @Stephan: Yes ..u r right ..i'm luking for HTTP status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` for this as in the sample below. The key here is the `getResponseCode` method that will return the HTTP code, i.e. 200, 400... .

```
package so;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpRequest {

    private int getWebPageStatus(String url) {

        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            return con.getResponseCode();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (con != null) {
                con.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        System.out.println("https://login.yahoo.com  :" + request.getWebPageStatus("https://login.yahoo.com"));
        System.out.println("https://www.google.co.in :" + request.getWebPageStatus("https://www.google.co.in"));
        System.out.println("https://www.gmail.com    :" + request.getWebPageStatus("https://www.gmail.com"));
        System.out.println("https://xyz.co.in        :" + request.getWebPageStatus("https://xyz.co.in"));
    }

}
```

Comment: :- Thanks for your answer. I would like know that before connection i.e  con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(); to implement URLEncoder?